# How to check if the home activity was launched?

Tags: android

How can I check inside the OnRestart method, if the home button was released ?

or

When the home button is released then the following intent is called Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/.Launcher }.

How to check inside the method onRestart that the above Intent was called ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use just a clickListener? Checking at onRestart seems pointless, for the user could completely pass the check and make it useless. Or you halt everything until the check is passed which would also not be smooth for the user. Use a listener and attach it to the homebutton.

Answer (score 0):

this is Home Button which is launching Home Activity (it's a key called Home reserved by Android to quit app or like an emergency exit), I know that OnKeyDown is no way to catch that key ? I was thinking the other way around to figure out when the Home Activity came out . 
I tried the following code:
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SE RVICE);

List rs = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for (int i=0; i

}

The PID is the one that I need but the process always show me System, if it was a way to get from PID the following :
ActivityManager(81): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/.Launcher }
then that could solve my request about to know when Home activity came out ...